# Add new control and resize container to fit accordingly

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I'm working on a Blackjack game for school and I need a container, which will be containing Image controls.

I want to have a container in which Image controls will be created (through code) to house the images for the cards which the player has hit. This can be up to 9 cards when working with a single deck, like I am.

As for my question:
What would be the easiest/lowest impact way to create each Image control so that the center across all of the controls are aligned with the center of my "hand" Image controls?

Here's a quick illustration with what I mean:

[image: Example]

So basically:
If the amount of cards is uneven (1,3,5,7 or 9), the center of the middle card is centered above the hand.

If the amount of cards is even (2,4,6 or 8), the space in between the 2 middle cards is centered above the hand.

Comment: What happens in the case where there is only 1 card? Does it align to horizontal centre in the bottom row?

Comment: @goobering I haven't tried anything yet, I'm still unsure as to which type of control I should use as a container (thinking Grid), which is part of my question.

Comment: The type of control changes depending on that condition - what would you *like* it to do?

Comment: Well, then I would say: As in the image, it should simply align the middle card (the only card in this case) with the center of the 2 cards in the bottom row. Unless you mean the case when the bottom row only has 1 card, which won't happen (as with Blackjack you always get dealt 2 cards for your hand)

Comment: Do the cards in the top row overlap each other?

Comment: No, I may end up having the bottom row slightly overlapping (purely for a prettier UI), but the top row will never have overlapping images.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this, replacing Rectangles with Images as appropriate:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Rectangle Width="100"
                Height="100"
                Fill="Blue" />
        <Rectangle Width="100"
                Height="100"
                Fill="Green" />
        <Rectangle Width="100"
                Height="100"
                Fill="Blue" />
        <Rectangle Width="100"
                Height="100"
                Fill="Green" />
        <Rectangle Width="100"
                Height="100"
                Fill="Blue" />
        <Rectangle Width="100"
                Height="100"
                Fill="Green" />
        <Rectangle Width="100"
                Height="100"
                Fill="Blue" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Rectangle Width="100"
                       Height="100"
                       Fill="Red" />
            <Rectangle Width="100"
                       Height="100"
                       Fill="Black" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I've manually filled the StackPanels where normally you'd bind their ItemsSource properties to ObservableCollection(s).